# Which Silverlight Rich Text Box to use

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

SL4 now contains a Microsoft implementation of a RichTextBox.  This is awesome but doesn't support bullets, numbering, super script or subscript.

There are also a bunch of other RichTextBox implementations out there from the control providers.

When is the best time to use the Microsoft one and when should I go to the market?  What is the best control for the different use cases for a Rich Text control?

BTW, I'm not looking for subjective stuff.  I'm interested in functionality, performance, extensibility, download size etc

Answer (score 1):

performance? Forget about Microsoft`s RichTextBox. The WPF RichTextBox is a speed mess because its a FlowDocument. Silverlight is not different.